# mongoose find very slow but robomongo very fast

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My mongodb is installed on the remote machine, index enabled.
The collection document total count is about ***15 000 000***.
On my local machine, I use mongoose find() for search, finally returns ***60000*** results. 
But find() will take about ***70 seconds***. Then I use lean(), time cost is about ***40 seconds***, a little better but still too long.

Still on my local machine, I use robomongo client to connect to this remote mongodb, do the same search, only ***28ms***

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  monitorName : {type: String},
  value : {type: Number},
  updateDate : {type: String}
});
```

My search condition is as this:

```js
Model.find().where('updateDate').gt('1/18/2017, 11:37:25 PM').lt('1/19/2017, 11:37:25 PM').lean().exec(function(err, docs){ ......
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I don't understand what is your question ? , please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: have you created an index for updateDate ?

Comment: Yes, created. I guess robomongo client only show 50 results every page. May it automatically use paging?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Robomongo uses 
**`.limit(<n>)` & `.skip(<n>)`** (50 records)
by default.

So it doesn't retrieves as much collections as with a regular `.find()` operation.

It's probably to avoid cases where the user accidentally run huge queries that block the UI, and making the window unresponsive.

Comment: If so, most of time cost is used to transfer documents from network?

Comment: Yes it does use paging by default, because it's a GUI application it softens the user experience by preventing the user from accidentally running huge queries that block the UI.